# Guideline to email listener application on AWS

Tags: java, email-client

I am new to application development on AWS, and I'm interested in setting up a Gmail listener application sitting on this service. So this application is intended to work in such a way that it utilizes Oauth Authentication for users and then listens for new Gmail messages. I just wanted to clarify is there is a similar open source implementation or some tutorial that can guide me along the right line as I have been searching online and found nothing concrete.

I have currently created a local application using Javamail which listens for new email, however users have to type in security credentials. I would like a comprehensive tutorial on how to best deploy this to AWS